# Network adapter setup for Hyper-V causes continuous "Network change detected" for host PC

Tags: hyper-v

I have setup a server in Hyper-V on my work PC. This server needs to be accessed remotely and that is working fine.
To set this up I created a new Virtual Switch for this Server as the default switch didn't work. Now my work PC will regularly give me the error message "Network change detected" in chrome when browsing to a site, and it will take a while to connect to other PC's in remote desktop or via applications like FileMaker. If I disable this network in the control panel (The vEthernet adapter) then the host PC doesn't have the network change issue but ofcourse the server in Hyper-V is then no longer connected to the Internet.

[image: Hyper-v Virtual Switch]

[image: Network Adaptors]

[image]

Comment: Are you getting this issue with host PC restart? Change in IP address could be reason for Connection interruption when automatic IP is selected in the adaptor settings. May be static IP configuration in the adaptor can help you.

Comment: Static IP is already set and a restart doesn't make a difference. This has been going on for a few weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered on super user:

Leave the default switch as the true default. Do not change it.

Then make a New External Switch and use that. You need the External Switch for remote access.

I have use the external switch setup successfully.

https://superuser.com/questions/1805421/network-adapter-setup-for-hyper-v-causes-continuous-network-change-detected-fo/1805422#1805422